# How to check if user already sent message in channel?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I would like to block a user who want to send another message in a specific channel :

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    if ((message.content === config.RUN) && message.member.roles.cache.has(config.ROLE_ID)) {
        if (message.channel.type === 'DM') return;
                let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
                let destination = client.channels.cache.get(config.CHANNEL_ID);
                message.author.createDM().then(dmchannel => {
                    dmchannel.send(textDM.FIRST_DM);
                    const collector = new discord.MessageCollector(dmchannel, filter);
                    collector.on('collect', (m, col) => {
                        console.log(m.content);
                        if (m.content.startsWith("ok")) { // here condition if user already sent msg

                          // Do something 

                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to count the quantity of the message sent by the user. If it reaches `2`, you can execute your desired code.

To use this for specific user, do:

```js
var messageAmount = {}
var amount = 0

if (message.content.startsWith("ok")) {

        const user = message.author.id

        if(messageAmount[`${user}`] === 1) { // is 1 because it checks for 2 after it has been assigned, if(messageAmount = x-1) 

            // Do something 
            message.channel.send("You cannot say that again until (...) finishes")


            // then reset it
            messageAmount[`${user}`] = 0
            amount = 0

        } else {
                
            ++amount
    
            messageAmount[`${user}`] = amount
        }
    }
```

To use this globally:

```js
var messageAmount = 0


if (m.content.startsWith("ok")) {

    ++messageAmount

    if(messageAmount === 2) {
          // Do something 
    }
}
```